# If $V(x) =\frac{c}{|x|}$,how to prove that $\varepsilon>0$ exists such this condition holds true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let $V:\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $V(x) =\frac{c}{|x|}$, with $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
During my math class the Professor said that:

1. $\lim_{|x|\to +\infty} |\nabla V(x)|= 0$

(I agree about that) and, in addition,

2. $x\cdot \nabla V(x)$ is negative for any $x$ and $\varepsilon_0 >0, \gamma \ge 1$ exists such that $$x\cdot\nabla V(x)\le -c|x|^{-\gamma}$$
   for any $|x|<\varepsilon_0$ (I agree about that, too).

In particular, he said that from condition 2. it follows that a number $\varepsilon>0$ small enough exists such that
$$-x\cdot\nabla V(x)\ge c\frac{1}{|x|} +c_1\frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}}, \quad\mbox{ for } |x|<\varepsilon,$$
where $\gamma>\alpha>0$.

I am in trouble with the condition 3.
I tried to compute $x\cdot\nabla V(x)$ which should be
$$x\cdot\nabla V(x) =x\cdot \left(-c \frac{x}{|x|^3}\right)= -c \frac{1}{|x|}$$
but I don't understand why condition 3 holds true.
Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: seems that the claim is true with $c=1$ and $c_1=0$? do I miss something?

Comment: @daw no, it is right. It is the reason why I don't understand why add the term with $c_1 |q|^{-\alpha}$.

Comment: Be careful of the wording. He said "from condition 2, it follows that ...". I.e., he is claiming condition 3 holds true for any $V$ satisfying condition 2, not just for $V = \frac c{|x|}$.